# Apache2 / mod_wsgi causing Import Error

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, flask, mod-wsgi

This is really annoying me now.

I am trying to deploy my Flask application to my Ubuntu VPS via mod_wsgi and an Apache server.

Whenever I start the Apache server, it appears to run just fine. However, whenever I try to go to my VPS' URL, I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

When looking at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I see this:

```
Loading WSGI script '/var/www/Giveaways/giveaways.wsgi'.
Target WSGI script '/var/www/Giveaways/giveaways.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/Giveaways/giveaways.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/Giveaways/giveaways.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
    from Giveaways import application as application
  File "/var/www/Giveaways/Giveaways/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, request
ImportError: No module named 'flask'
```

This is the `giveaways.wsgi` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

activate_this = '/var/www/Giveaway/Giveaway/venv3-5/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "somefile.py", 'exec')
    exec(code)

import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/Giveaways/")

from Giveaways import application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

The strange thing is, even though I have 3 versions of Python installed (2.7, 3.4 and 3.50, they ALL have the flask package installed, so this issue has me stumped.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the virtual env?  Is flask installed in the virtual environment? what does source   /var/www/Giveaway/Giveaway/venv3-5/bin/activate;python -c "import flask" produce?

Comment: It produces no output at all and simply ends. I have actually installed flask *inside* the virtual environment *as well as* globally.

Comment: I fear that the #!/usr/bin/python3.5 isn't doing what you expect.  You may need to rebuild mod_wsgi (https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/QuickInstallationGuide.wiki) against your 3.5 python install

Comment: You might add  import platform:print platform.python_version() to your wsgi file to verify

Comment: @Stanton I put the import and print statement in my .wsgi file. Just running `python giveaways.wsgi` outputs `3.5.0+`, but there is no extra output in the error.log.

Comment: But what's in the error_log for apache when you hit the URL?

Comment: I have tried refreshing the URL page (still a 500 error), but I still do not see any extra output in the error log, just the same import error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103054/discussion-between-nat-karmios-and-stanton).